# Netlify CLI nextjs runtime deployment - fail to find page

Tags: next.js, netlify, netlify-cli

In full transparency I have created this issue here because Netlify forum won't let me post more then 1 media link on an issue and I wanted to provide additional details to the issue. That post can be found [here](https://answers.netlify.com/t/ci-nextjs-deployment-with-next-js-runtime/82931).

**Problem:**

Deploying monorepo application via Netlify CLI results in "Not Found error" due to not picking up the [`@netlify/plugin-nextjs`](https://github.com/netlify/next-runtime) plugin for nextjs runtime but works correctly via UI production deployments.

**Required info:**

- Repo: [pr-with-deployment-issue](https://github.com/webb-tools/webb-dapp/pull/849)
- Site with error deployment: https://63bc6cdb745e5c0d82dcc4eb--webbsite-dev.netlify.app/

**Deployment settings:**

[image: buildsetting]

**Background:**

Our team is using both Netlify CLI / GitHub Actions and the UI to deploy a Netlify site. The deployment via GitHub Actions is for development previews and deployments via Netlify UI is for our staging environment. We prefer making use of Netlify CLI / GitHub Actions for flexibility in our dev previews. You can see that workflow [here](https://github.com/webb-tools/webb-dapp/blob/trung-tin/marketing-mobile-view-and-email-subsription/.github/workflows/landing-page-dapp-dev.yml).

**UI Deployment that works:**

The deployments via the UI works perfectly fine with the installed next.js runtime. You can see that deployment [here](https://63bc4a46c7345a32d0301d75--webbsite-dev.netlify.app/). It correctly processes rules, edge functions and runtime usage.

[image: ui-deployment|690x321]

**Netlify CLI / GitHub Action deployment that does not work:**

Deploying the site using Netlify CLI and the `@netlify/plugin-nextjs` plugin does not work as intended. Deployment steps used:

1. Install @netlify/plugin-nextjs as dev dependency
2. Create `netlify.toml` file with following contents:

```
[[plugins]]
package = "@netlify/plugin-nextjs"

[build]
command = "yarn build:webbsite"
publish = "./dist/apps/webbsite/.next"
```

3. Run `netlify deploy context=deploy-preview site=$NETLIFY_WEBBSITE_ID --dir=./dist/apps/webbsite/.next`

Successfully deploys the site:

[image: success]

BUT....

[image: cli-deployment]

AND...

[image: error not found]

**Expected Result**

I want to be able to trigger dev-preview deployments using the Netlify CLI that correctly deploy the site with nextjs runtime AND keep the working as intended deployment via the UI for production deployments. If the `netlify.toml` must be used, ideally I would like that to exist in the specific apps subdirectory.

Also the GH workflow works fine for all other next.js / netlify deployments that do not depend on next.js runtime usage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have exhausted all documentation / resources to this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Needed to add `--build` flag in my deployment command.

`netlify deploy --build context=deploy-preview site=$NETLIFY_WEBBSITE_ID --dir=./dist/apps/webbsite/.next`

For those, like me, who needed to deploy from root but needed a `netlify.toml` config file to live in the package/subdir. During the GH action workflow I just added a step to copy a `netlify.toml` config from package/subdir (e.g. `package/app1`) to root prior to executing deployment command mentioned above.